# Visual Studio 2010 errors in release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with VisualStudio 2010. When I switch to release mode I get errors:
-"The type or namespace could not be found",
-"The name  does not exist in the current context". 
There is no errors in debug mode, just in release. 
I will be grateful for eny help.

Comment: I think the error is straight forward "The type or namespace could not be found". Check if you have any references from the bin\debug folder change them to project references